# Combinations of Transcendental Numbers are still transcendental numbers?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

We know there are numbers like $\pi$, $e$, $\phi$ or also $\zeta(3)$ which are **transcendental** numbers.

I was wondering if combinations of transcendental numbers are still transcendental numbers, like $e + \pi$ or $\frac{1}{\phi}$ or whatever.

Comment: We don't even know if $e+\pi$ is rational or not, never mind whether it is transcendental.

Comment: The golden ratio, $\phi$ is algebraic.  It satisfies $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$.

Comment: It is also not known whether $\zeta(3)$ is transcendental. It has only been proven to be irrational.

Comment: @lulu Whoops, my bad. I made a mistake!

Comment: @Dylan I guess the answer is then "we don't know" or better: "it depends" :D

Comment: You might like to look into [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e+\pi$ and $e\pi$ both can not be rational, because if both be rational then  we have $x^2-(e+\pi)x+e\pi=0$ has roots $\pi$ and $e$ and leads to contradiction. Also if $z$ is transcendental, then $\frac{1}{z}$ is transcendental, if not then we have $\sum_{i=0}^na_i(\frac{1}{z})^i=0$ for some $a_i\in \mathbb{Z},a_n\not = 0$ and this means $\sum_{i=0}^na_{n-i}z^i=0$, if there exists a $j<n$ such that $a_j\not =0$, this leads to contradiction because it shows that $z$ is algebraic and if for all $j<n$ we have $a_j=0$, then we have $\frac{a_n}{z}=0$ and it contradicts by $a_n\not =0$.

Comment: Wow thank you sir. Astounding answer!!

Answer (score 9):

Hint:

$\pi $ and $1-\pi$ are transcendental. What about $\pi+(1-\pi)$?

Comment: That's cool! I guess that then we cannot say it a priori. It depends upon numbers we have..

Answer (score 3):

Polynomials over the rationals in one transcendental number are transcendental, almost (but not quite) by definition. $e^5 + 3e^3 - 2e + 2$ is transcendental.

In two transcendental numbers...  well of course $\pi + (1-\pi)$ is rational.

And as for $e + \pi$, who knows?

Comment: I believe not all such polynomials are transcendental. For instance $e^2 + be^2 - 1$ is not transcendental where $b$ is defined such that $e^2 + be^2 - 1 = 0$. Perhaps you meant all polynomials with rational algebraic linearly independent coefficients by the Lindemann Weierstrass theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem.

Comment: @abligh fixed (to something narrower but intuitive)